# Проверить существование базы данных

Tags: bash

Здравствуйте, пишу bash-скрипт добавления виртуальных хостов на сервере. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно проверить существование MySQL базы данных по названию?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выложите свой скрипт.
Вот пример:

```
#!/bin/bash

MyUSER="xxx"
MyPASS="xxx"
MyHOST="localhost"

MYSQL="$(which mysql)"
MYSQLDUMP="$(which mysqldump)"

#MYSQL="/usr/local/bin/mysql"
#MYSQLDUMP="/usr/local/bin/mysqldump"

CHOWN="$(which chown)"
CHMOD="$(which chmod)"
GZIP="$(which gzip)"

DEST="/home/xxx/test/mysql_db"

MBD="$DEST"
HOST="$(hostname)"
NOW="$(date +"%Y%m%d")"

FILE=""
DBS=""

# DO NOT BACKUP these databases, delemiter SPACE
IGN="information_schema
performance_schema
phpmyadmin
mysql
test"
DBS="$($MYSQL -u $MyUSER -h $MyHOST -p$MyPASS -Bse 'show databases')"
for db in $DBS
do

skipdb=-1
if [ "$IGN" != "" ]; then
    for i in $IGN
    do
        [ "$db" == "$i" ] && skipdb=1 || :
    done
fi

if [ "$skipdb" == "-1" ] ; then
    MBD="$DEST/$db"
    [ ! -d $MBD ] && mkdir -p $MBD || :
    FILE="$MBD/$NOW.sql.gz"
        $MYSQLDUMP --events --skip-lock-tables --opt -u $MyUSER -h $MyHOST -p$MyPASS $db | $GZIP -9 > $FILE
    FNUM="$(find $MBD/* | wc -l)"
    if [ $FNUM -ge 0 ] ; then
        find $MBD/* -type f -mtime 20 -exec rm -rf {} \;
    fi
fi
```

done